# How to add Attribute to this Element (Schemas)

Tags: xml, schema

I have the following Schema Element and I'd like to add an Attribute to it.

```
<xsd:ComplexType>
    <xsd:sequence>    
       <xsd:element name="Product" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" >
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:maxLength value="100" />
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:ComplexType>
```

Right now the resulting XML looks like:

```
<Product>This is the Product Translation for 001</Product>
```

I want the resulting XMl to look like:

```
<Product code="001">This is the Product Translation for 001</Product>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick:

```
<xsd:ComplexType>
    <xsd:sequence>    
        <xsd:element name="Product" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" >
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:maxLength value="100" />
                </xsd:restriction>
                <xsd:attribute name="code" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:ComplexType>
```

you might wish to specify a different type for the attribute `code`.

Comment: This would require me to create a new object for name="code" when I use JAXB to create an object. is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: sorry, i don't know of any.